# Explain some basic concepts in simple linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

So I was just making a simple linked list in C. I was a bit confused as to why the linked list was able to be formed when others used node references and used return functions but mine worked with void functions. Is it because I declared the head pointer globally and the functions just modifies and uses the pointer for createlist func and print func respectively?? My concept in references is weak. Thanks for helping out!

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;

} node;

node *head = NULL;

void data(int item)
{
    node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->data = item;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        node *ptr = head;
        while (ptr->next != NULL)
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next = newnode;
    }
}

void print()
{
    node *ptr = head;
    printf("%d ->", ptr->data);

    while (ptr->next != NULL)
    {

        ptr = ptr->next;
        printf("%d ->", ptr->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid global variables when you can.  Don't cast void pointers.  You are missing stdlib.h (for malloc).

Comment: Your LL appends nodes to the tail after traversing the entire list to find the tail... A challenge to explore: Maintain a pointer to the last node of the LL so that this traversal is not necessary...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since you are using global head pointer, it's fine to assign newnode directly,
the reason why use node reference is beacause in C, all func call param is default pass by value, changes made to the parameter inside the function have no effect on the argument.

So if you need change your head pointer, you need one more layer indirection, that's need pass a node** head parameter, inside your func, just do *head = newnode, will do works.
or if pass pointer to func, you need return the new head pointer, otherwise new malloced head node memory leaks, since it not change your pass in pointer at all.

Answer (score 2):

> when others used node references and used return functions but mine worked with void functions. Is it because I declared the head pointer globally

The short answer is: Yes by using a global variable you circumvent the normal struggles of updating a head-pointer inside a function. Your code gets simpler but it comes with a price - a big price.

A simple linked list is often of the form:

```
struct node
{
    T data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct node * head = NULL;

    ....

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to have a function to add new nodes to the list, that function must be able to change the value of `head` defined in `main`. As C uses pass-by-value you can't just pass `head` to the function - the function won't be able to change the value of `head` in `main`, it can only change a local variable initially having the same value.

Two ways of "solving" that is

1. Let the function return the possibly new `head` value.

Like:

```
struct node * insert(struct node * head, T data)
{
    ... add node which may include head = malloc(....), i.e. head is changed

    return head;  // Return the possibly changed head
}

int main(void)
{
    struct node head = NULL;

    head = insert(head, ...);

    ....

    return 0;
}
```

2. Pass a pointer to `head` so that the function can change the value of `head`  by using the pointer

Like:

```
void insert(struct node ** phead, T data)
{
    ... add node which may include *phead = malloc(....), i.e. head is changed
                                   ^^^^^
                               Change head using the pointer

}

int main(void)
{
    struct node head = NULL;

    insert(&head, ...);

    ....

    return 0;
}
```

**Back to your question...** Correct, since you have `head` as a global variable, you avoid all that. Your insert-function can just read and modify the global variable and there is no need for passing anything to the function or returning anything from the function.

Kind of nice but there is a big downside... You can only have one list in your program. If you need a second list, you'll have to duplicate all the code. That's bad design. So avoid that global variable and use one of the two "usual ways".

That said... there are alternatives.

For instance by wrapping the `head` pointer in another struct. Like:

```
struct list
{
    struct node* head;
};
```

Now the `insert` function could be `void insert(struct list* list, T data)` and in `main` you would have code like: `struct list * list = calloc(....); insert(list, ...);`. In this way you avoid dealing with address-of, double pointers and return values.

Wrapping `head` in another struct is especially useful in case you want to store more information about the list than just the `head` pointer. For instance:

```
struct list
{
    struct node* head;
    struct node* tail;  // For fast list append implementation
    size_t size;        // For tracking number of list elements
};
```

Another "trick" I have seen used in order to get around the "update head" problem is to require that a list always has at least one element (i.e. a fixed `head`). That element would then be considered as an element not holding any data. This trick has a little memory overhead but simplifies other code.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing technical wrong (see below though) with your implementation that relies on global variables.  Global variables can be modified anywhere, and therein lies the problem, you have audit your entire code base to figure out where it's being changed.  Contrasted with a functional programming style where each function documents in its arguments what is being used and what is being modified:

```
void print(const node *root) {
    for(; root; root = root->next)
        printf("%d%s", root->data, root->next ? " -> " : "\n");
}
```

You can only have a single instance of your linked list in your program.  As a generic data type that is problematic.  Even if you only need a single instance, you may need to test your code and only having a single instance gets in the way.

The other thing to consider is the concept of encapsulation.  You may want to hide the implementation details from the user of your library.  This allows change your implementation without disrupting users of your library.  For example, you may decide that 200% overhead storing a 64 bit pointer for each 32 bit data value is excessive, so you may decide that each node should hold an array of, say, 32 data values so overhead is now only 6.25%.

Global variables also makes multi-treating a lot more complicated as you now have to lock shared data for both reading and writing operations.

There are defects, of course, like your `print()` will segfault if `head` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

In addtional to avoid using global varibles.  Be careful that you should check if **head** is **nullptr** or not before print it out.

```
void print()
{ 
    node *ptr = head; # if you never add item into the linklist, you will get into trouble.
    printf("%d ->", ptr->data);
```

It will be safer as below

```
void print()
{ 
    node *ptr = head; 
    if( ptr )
    {
        printf("%d ->", ptr->data);
        while( .... )
    }
```

}